# How to pass a javascript variable value to a jsp value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have a JavaScript functionality that change the value dynamically on selecting a list box ,i am able to get that value in a text field using the id.But i want to get that value in a jsp variable  that i am not able to get this is what i have done ,

```
          <div class="form-control">
                <label class="lebelMergin" for="_Manager">
                <span class="spanMergin"></span>
             <input type='text' class='text' name='business1' id="hiddenField" /> 
                </label>
            </div>
```

jquery

```
$('#branch_branchTypeId').on('change', function (event) {
   //var vl = $("option:selected",this).text();
   var vl = $(this).val();      
   var myvalue=$("option:selected",this).text();
   $('.text').val(myvalue);
   document.getElementById("hiddenField").value=myvalue;

    var target = $("#business");
    if (vl) {
        target.show();
    } else {
        target.hide();
    }
});
```

This is showing the value in the div using id.but i want that id in a script variable.

Comment: @Thilo thanks for answering but from  that question i can not set the value of myvalue in jsp variable

Comment: You need to send the value to the server somehow. Possibly via Ajax.

Comment: i am using it in the same jsp page

Comment: The Javascript is run *after* the JSP has already *finished*.

Comment: Why do you need to populate a JSP variable? You can perform dynamic dropdown value change using JS only. Is there any specific reason for setting a JSP variable?

Answer (score 1):

The only ways is AJAX, use AJAX to make call to the server and send all your data along with it, possibly in JSON format.

Answer (score 0):

Use of Jquery's `load()` will be the best solution which uses `parameters` and `URL` which to be called [use this link to get more reference](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

**Code snippet**:

`$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); 
                $("#Divsection").load(URLofresourceofAjax,{ "param1OfRequest":value,"Param2":value});`